# What's best practice for Angular2+ use/store web service credentials?

Tags: angular, web, frontend, firebase-security

As far as I understand, the deployment for angular would be built and bundled to a dist directory, which get distributed to a server, and in the end served to client side. However, this raised my question, if there's a back-end webservice requires BASIC Authentication, does that mean the username and password for access the webservice will also get render to client side with the bundled JavaScript file?

Any input would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is yes, if you have those credentials as plain text in your app then they will be bundled with the client side code and visible to anyone who inspects the code.

If you want to hide this information, and you definitely do, the standard solution is that instead of your client-side app having the credentials and making the API call itself, your app should call a route on your server, which has the credentials instead, and uses them and makes the API call itself and returns the result.

Upside: Your credentials aren't visible in plain text to anyone who uses the site.

Downside: There will be a overhead time as you are now calling an API that calls another API instead of calling said API directly.